# How to Acess Dynamic Form Elements id Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, dynamic

I am using PHP and Javascript For Creating Dynamic Form Element i can access the Dynamic Form Elements Value Using PHP..

But my requirement is Before Send Data to Server i want to calculate Tax and Discounts to my individual products..
and Show total price

### WORKS FINE FOLLOWS:

I can add the form element dynamically
Post Dynamic products  Values to the servers

### PROBLEM :

Calculate Tax and discount for all Dynamic Products individually 
and show the details before send data to server..

i want to show the total price for individual products

THANKS...

### THIS IS MY CODE FOR ADD DYNAMIC ELEMENTS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  if(rowCount < 20){        `enter code here`       `enter code here`             // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i <colCount; i++) {
      var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
      newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
  }
else{
     alert("Maximum Passenger per ticket is 5");         

 }
}
</script>
```

### MY HTML FORM CODE:

```
<table id="dataTable" class="form" border="0" width="100%" border="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
  <p>


  <td width="15%">
  <label for="BX_birth">Product name</label>
  <select class="form-control" style="width:70%;" id="BX_birth" name="pname[]">
    <option>....</option>
   <?php
                    include_once "connection.php";
                    $qry="SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE `totqty` NOT LIKE '0' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
                    $res=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
                     $id=$row['id'];
                     $name=$row['name'];


                    ?>

                    <option><?php echo $name; ?></option>
                    <?php
                  }
                    ?>
  </select>
  </td>



  <td width="15%">
      <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Qty</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pqty[]" id="qty" oninput="calculate()"   placeholder="">
                </div>
  </td>
  <td width="15%">
      <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Rate</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prate[]" id="rate" oninput="calculate()"    placeholder="">
                </div>
  </td>

    </td>
  <td width="15%">
      <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Discount</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="discount[]" id="discount" oninput="calculate()"    placeholder="">
                </div>
  </td>

    </td>
  <td width="15%">
      <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Sub Total</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subtotal[]" id="subtotal" oninput="calculate()"    placeholder="">
                </div>
  </td>

   <td width="15%">
      <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">VAT(%)</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vat[]" id="vat" oninput="calculate()"   placeholder="">
                </div>
  </td>

   <td width="15%">
      <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Total</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total[]" id="total" oninput="calculate()"    placeholder="">
                </div>
  </td>






</p>
  </p>
  </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

### MY PHP CODE FOR GET DYNAMIC FORM VALUES:

```
foreach( $pname as $key => $n ) {
  $pn=$pname[$key];
  $pr=$prate[$key];
  $pq=$pqty[$key];

}
```

### MY FORM:

[image: my form]

http://techmyntra.co.in/website-designing-and-development-company-vellor.html

http://www.techmyntra.co.in

Comment: write onkeyup() function in javascript while calculating you. will display the result.

Comment: Suppose your product `id` is unique. so making `<input type="hidden" id="product<?php echo $product['id']?>" value="" />` this type of input can generate unique id for each product dom element.Same for the others.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP while generating form

Suppose you are using while loop to generate dynamic form

```
$index = 1;
while(.....)
{
   $id1 = "MyField_".$index;

   echo "<input type='text' id=$id1 />";

   $id2 = "MyField2_".$index;
   echo "<input type='text' id=$id1 onblur='total($index);' />";

   $idTotal = "MYTotalField_".$index;
   echo "<input type='text' id=$idTotal />";

   $index++;

}

//--[JS Method]--
function total(index)
{
  var value1 = $("#MyField_"+index).val();
  var value2 = $("#MyField2_"+index).val();
  .
  .
  var valuen = $("#selectorn").val();


  var total = value1 + value2 + .... + valuen;
  $("#MYTotalField_"+index).val(total);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Suppose he has 5 products and then how he can get the value by `$(selector).val()` if those products generated dynamically from database?

Comment: Yes..it works but i can calculate the product values only first product on my form.. but  it not works for second product..kindly see my form

Comment: You will need to generate unique ids for each input field. 
Let me edit answer for reference.